# Новая запись в ListView,заполняемого из БД SQLite, появляется только после закрытия приложения

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

В активити из определённых переменных, по кнопке создается БД. Затем во фрагменте эта БД открывается и заполняется ListView. Проблема заключается в том, что новая запись в этом ListView появляется только после закрытия приложения, т.е. как я понимаю происходит какое-то обновление.Никак не возьму в толк, как мне сделать так, чтобы запись в списке фрагмента появлялась сразу по нажатию кнопки в активити.

Comment: ListView заполняется до того как появилась запись ! Поэтому после добавления записи в БД её нужно добавить и в ListView !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дайте ListView знать о том что произошли какие-то изменения.

```
 notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: т.е. после закрытия приложения, обновления происходят не в самой базе данных, а в обновлении самого ListView?

Comment: Когда вы закрываете приложение и открываете заново, отрабатывает OnCreate, значит ListView считывает данные с БД. Вам нужно дать списку знать о том что произошли какие-то изменения.
У меня была подобная ситуация, но не с бд. Я менял название файла в ListView, а notifyDataSetChanged(); забыл прописать, список и не видел что файл поменял название,и не обновлялся.

Comment: Спасибо! Думаю вы меня правильно направили, позже попробую.

Answer (score 1):

Если используете **SimpleCursorAdapter** и имплементируете **`LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`**, то можно использовать:

`getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);`